# Downloading variable file name in IE with no save prompt

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to download a spreadsheet, whose name changes each time the temporary is loaded when accessed, without dealing with IE save prompt.  The intranet site routes through a portal, which requires windows authentication to log in, before taking me to my destination.  What I have pieced together so far gets me through the windows authentication, enters the appropriate information and clicks the button to retrieve the query.  Ideally I would like to pull the information directly, without save prompting, to my N: drive and simply save it as "File.xlsx"; navigating the download/save prompt would work as well, but I have no idea which would be easier or more efficient to accomplish.

```
Sub Automation()

Const URL1 = "https://website/q/?ICAction=ICQryNameExcelURL=PUBLIC.Z_FILE_DESIGN"

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim DValue As String

Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
DValue = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")

With IE
    .Navigate URL1
    .Visible = True
End With

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy

IE.Navigate "javascript: signinIWA();"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
HTMLDoc.getElementById("InputKeys_Z_File").Value = "q32e751"
HTMLDoc.getElementById("InputKeys_EFFDT").Value = DValue

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4 And Not IE.Busy

HTMLDoc.getElementById("#ICQryDownloadExcelFrmPrompt").Click

End Sub
```

If it helps at all, the code when inspecting the click button element:

```
</DIV></td>
</tr>
<input type='hidden' name='ICExcel' id='ICExcel' value='1' />
</table>
<a class='PSPUSHBUTTON' style='background-Color: transparent;border:0;' id = 'Left' role='presentation'><span style='background-Color: transparent;border:0;'><input type='button' class='PSPUSHBUTTON' value='View Results' id='#ICQryDownloadExcelFrmPrompt' onclick="submitAction_win4(this.form,'#ICQryDownloadExcelFrmPrompt');" tabindex='14' /></span></a>
</DIV>
<DIV id='win4divQUERYRESULT'><table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' width='90%'>
<tr><td>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>`
```

The one thing that does change each time accessed is the number "4" in the onclick action and queryresult line following.  Also, when the temporary file is opened it always has the same basic name - Z_FILE_DESIGN, but includes a random number attached, eg. Z_FILE_DESIGN_12345. Any suggestions or assistance are greatly appreciated.